# Cambiar el valor de un input type=text mediante botón - JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, botón, entrada

Aquí mi problema:

Quiero que al presionar sobre el botón, en el `input type="text"` aparezca el `value` introducido.

```js
document.addEventListener("load", cargaPagina);
function cargaPagina() {
  document.getElementById("boton1").addEventListener("click", cambiaValores);
}

function cambiaValores() {
   var inputNombre = document.getElementsById("nombre");
  inputNombre.value = "DYP";
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">


        Nombre <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" value=""><br><br> <!--nombre, input-->

        <input type="button" id="boton1" name="boton1" value="cambia nombre"><br><br> <!--boton-->

    </form>
```

Comment: `getElementsById` es en singular `getElementById` y el `listener` debe ser al objeto `window` y no  al documento , `window.addEve....`

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias de nuevo! @Dev.Joel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dos errores puntuales

- `getElementsById` no existe,  lo correcto sería en singular. `getElementById`
- `document.addEventListener("load", cargaPagina);` el evento load se dispara al objeto `window` *(entre otros)* y no al documento. [referencia](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#events-2) , si desea añadir un evento de carga al `document` lo correcto sería  `DOMContentLoaded`

  ```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", cargaPagina);
  ```

```js
window.addEventListener("load", cargaPagina);
function cargaPagina() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("boton1").addEventListener("click", cambiaValores);
}

function cambiaValores() {
    var inputNombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
    inputNombre.value = "DYP";
}
```

```html
Nombre <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" value=""><br>
        <input type="button" id="boton1" name="boton1" value="cambia nombre">
```

Comment: Te me adelantaste por segundos jejeje saludos !

Comment: ¡Menudo fallo más tonto! Muchas gracias por la observación, ahora sí funciona correctamente. @Dev.Joel